# Click row on JQuery Data Table example

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I'm using jQuery DataTable Ajax grid. I want to trigger the row click event. I execute following code in sequence but it doesn't execute.

```
        $('#category tbody tr').click(function () {
            alert('e');
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var oTable = $('#category').dataTable( {
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": false,
                "sAjaxSource": "sources/category.txt"
            } );
        } );
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference. live function worked well.

```
        $('#category tbody tr').live('click', function() {
            alert('e');
        });
```

Comment: This should be obvious as you're using an AJAX source for your datatable.  If you were operating over an HTML table that was already in your markup, not using live would work just fine.

Comment: Ah yup. live has to be there for this AJAX source. Thanks.